# why EIO Error(Input/Output Error) appears frequently and is mostly solved with e2fsck

Tags: linux, ext4, inode, xubuntu

We have prepared a customized Linux system (ISO image with 15 GB size and all the packages we need are installed inside it) and we copy this image into different PCs with Different Intel Processors for quick installation (using **dd** command).

these linux PCs are used for storing camera images inside them, we also wrote a bash file to delete the oldest images when the hard disk reaches to 80 percent of its capacity ( so we don't run out of space)

it happens after a while (maybe 2days,1 week or 1 month after the linux installation) a Input/Output Error in the system which no command can't be run in the terminal except **e2fsck**
and mostly after running this command the system starts to operate again. (it will face the same error again in the future)

These are some of the error messages on some PCs:

```
PC1: sh: 1: /usr/bin/xauth: Input/output error
bash: /etc/bash.bashrc: Input/output error

PC2: Entry 'Image88982736' in /home/camera/store/2021/8/21/ (2262038) has deleted/unused inode 7367205.

PC3: Problem in HTREE directory inode 2393154: block #6 has bad max hash

PC4: Unconnected directory inode 8682665 (/home/camera/store/2021/08/16/???)

PC5: /usr/bin/xauth:  error in locking authority file /home/anpr/.Xauthority


PC6: Inode 262516 was part of the orphaned inode list
```

My question is that why this happens ?

A). is it because of the bash file we wrote for removing the oldest files ? ( it is a simple bash file which list the images based on the creation time and remove them simply by **rm** commmand)

B). is it because of multiple write/erase operations on the hard disk ( we write more than 100K images with size 200KB ~ 20GB of data each day is written and 20GB of data each day is erased)

C).is it because of the inode limit on ext4 file system ?

Also it is worth noting that sometimes it isn't solved with **e2fsck** and we have to install the OS again and that's what makes problem here !

Edit:

the way I prepared this customized Linux is that first I installed a fresh Linux (Xubuntu/Ubuntu) on a PC and then installed all the required packages on it.
Then I boot with a live Linux and backup the partition using dd to a specific File
e.g

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/home/media/ExternalHarddisk/Linux.iso bs=1M count=14482 status=progress
```

and then I resize the partition to its maximum capacity.

we have worked with this method for more than 2 years and not even a PC had problem in booting or file system.

the problem happens when we use these PCs in our project sites where they have to store/erase camera images

Comment: Try `dmesg`. It will show the errors you get above but might provide other errors as well. You'd know if there are *media* errors or not (but a failing SD doesn't always tell about this). This could also be caused by the way you "have prepared a customized Linux system" that isn't described in the question.

Comment: Yes, look for hardware problems like electrical interference from nearly machines, or it entering via a noisy mains power supply; mechanical shaking of internal cabling or hard disks, overheating, sudden large variations in temperature. The sata bus will auto negociate a suitable speed at the start, but then may generate IO errors when pushed into heavy use, and would need to be manually forced to a lower speed.

Comment: Have you verified the "dd" image with e2fsck right after copying it to verify that there is no corruption?  Maybe your source filesystem is not flushed consistently to disk, or the journal is not flushed completely, and using "dd" causes some corruption?

Comment: @meuh we have power supply with noise cancelling circuit, and also I mentioned in the question that whenever we use this for camera image storing this errors happens, if we dont' connect them to cameras nothing will happen since we don't have that much read and write in the hard disk.

Comment: @LustreOne after each dd we use <<sync>> command to make sure everything is written perfectly into the partition.  we just tried e2fsck last week and we saw no error concerning bad blocks or file system corruption ... so the image is fine I think